# How to binary-safe concatenate files on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to concatenate few large files (lets say 10 files of 20-50GB each) on Hadoop in a binary safe manner. I could write a specific loader/storage to do that but was wondering if there is a standard way to do it (eg Hadoop FS CLI)? I actually even do not care about content order.

Answer (score 1):

"getmerge" is what you are looking for -> http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.0/hdfs_shell.html#getmerge

Comment: This concatenates it locally, not remotely on the HDFS.